# Determine number of connected components

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

You are given a graph represented through an adjacency list. For example, the input

```
1-2 2-3 3-4 4-1
```

would correspond to the graph with nodes *1*, *2*, *3* and *4*, where *1* is connected to *2*, *2* is connected to *3*, *3* is connected to *4*, and *4* is connected to *1* (forming a square).

The task is to determine the number of of connected components of the graph represented by an inputted adjacency list. A "connected component" is a set of nodes from which there is no path to any other node that is not in the set.

Example:

> Intput: `1-2 2-3 4-5`
>   Output: `2`

---

Language of your choice - shortest code possible.

Comment: Does the input consist only of pairs of positive integers divided by a dash? The line "a lone node with no connections would be considered an unconnected component." would suggest otherwise.

Comment: @shiona Good point, I deleted that line. No lone nodes!

Comment: Usually, these would be called [_connected_ components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ruby, 77 characters

```
gets;0while$_.sub!(/\b(\d+)\b(.*) (\1-\d+|\d+-\1)\b/,'\3\2');p$_.count(" ")+1
```

A first plain attempt in Ruby. It collects the sub-graphs using a regular expression until no more connections can be made.

Examples:

```
> 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-1
1

> 1-2 2-3 4-5
2

> 1-2 3-4 8-9 1-6 5-7 7-4 10-9
3
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 126

With `x` holding the input string,

```
t = ToExpression; 
Length@ConnectedComponents@Graph[Characters /@ ImportString[x, "Table"][[1]] /. 
{a_, "-", b_} :>   UndirectedEdge[t@a, t@b]]
```

---

If `x` is input instead as a list of undirected edges, in standard Mathematica format, the solution can be reduced to 34 chars:

```
Length@ConnectedComponents@Graph@i
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 77

```
len(Graph([t.split('-')for t in raw_input().split()]).connected_components())
```

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript, <s>67</s> 62 characters

This can probably be golfed down a little more but...

<s>`" "/{"-"/{~}%}%0\{.}{(:^;{.{^&},.{+}*}{.@\-\{+}*:^;}while\)\}while;`</s>

```
'-'%{~}%2/0\{.}{(:^;{.{^&},.{+}*}{.@\-\{+}*:^;}while\)\}while;
```

Important note: this ONLY works on the ruby interpreter for golfscript (from golfscript.com), NOT on the online golfscript app, because the online app incorrectly handles nested while loops. Here's the commented code:

<s>`" "/{"-"/{~}%}%   # parse into array of number pairs`</s>

```
'-'%{~}%2/        # parse into array of number pairs
0\                # push the counter under the current set
{.}               # copy top for the condition pop
{
    (:^;          # grab leftmost pair
  {
    .{^&},        # grab any matching the left pair, make a copy for the
    .{+}*         # condition, and merge the copy's elements together
  }{
    .@\-\         # remove the matches from remaining set
    {+}*:^;       # merge matches together & assign to '^'
  }while
  \)\             # update the counter underneath
}while;
```