# Connecting Wires?

Tags: code-golf

Your goal is to create a program. It must take input indefinitely.

Here is a sample run (the `>` shows that the line is the output from the program)

```
2,6
> 0
5,6
> 0
7,5
> 0
2,7
> 1
```

Since 2 is connected to 6, which in turn is connected to 5 and then 7, 2 and 7 are hence connected.

```
5,2
> 1

...
```

#### Clarifications

Whenever the user writes any two numbers (separated by any delimiter you prefer), the program must output whether they are connected or not. If they are not connected, the program must output a falsy value (0), however if the wires are connected, the program must output a true value (1).

"We are to interpret the pair p-q as meaning “p is connected to q.” We assume the relation “is
connected to” to be transitive: If p is connected to q, and q is connected
to r, then p is connected to r."

The input must be separated from the output by a newline `\n`

The input will always be integers in base ten and never floats.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the shortest bytecount wins!

Comment: It's not very clear how the program is supposed to work. How exactly do we connect wires?

Comment: Its up to you? The user will enter the Input part i just wrote above, and the program should output whether the wires are already connected or they aren't.

Comment: Are all the input/output examples a part of 1 run of the program, or are they over multiple runs? If the latter is true, then can we store files?

Comment: @KritixiLithos I assume you just infinitely loop for input, would be weird to do it otherwise imo.

Comment: Yes they are a part of 1 run of the program.

Comment: Yes you infinitely loop for input.

Comment: Also, I think this question might be a bit trivial, so if there was a winning criteria, it would be easy to see the winner by judging the programs' byte count

Comment: @MuhamedCicak Can I edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yes i would really appreciate that. Please edit it so it is clearer.

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub I edited it to allow more flexible output options

Comment: @MuhamedCicak I edited the challenge so that it would be more specific and have more flexible I/O options. Feel free to edit it if you feel I missed out anything :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos I didn't wanted to make code golf. Just "Programming Puzzle" so the goal is to just make the program no matter how many bytes it is. Everything else you edited is perfect :)

Comment: @MuhamedCicak But if it just is a puzzle, there really won't be a way of selecting the winner from the multiple answers there will be. But if it is code-golf, then it will be easy to select a winner :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Ok then its ok to stay code-golf. I dont know why this question is still on hold.

Comment: @MuhamedCicak I have nominated it for reopening (and so has one other person). If it gets more reopen votes, then it won't be on hold any longer

Comment: I still see a few problems. 1. There is a self-contradiction in giving `> The wires were not connected. Connecting them...` as an example of a falsy value. 2. The assumption of transitivity is not sufficient to make the sample run correct. It requires also assuming symmetry. It is not clear whether in addition you expect answers to assume reflexivity. 3. The requirement to separate input from output by a newline seems to assume stdio, but there is no explicit requirement to use stdio. 4. Numbers in base 10 are decimals, so "*integers in base ten and never decimals*" is self-contradictory.

Comment: Note that after editing this is likely also to be a borderline dupe of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69926/194 and/or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8647/194

Comment: So this will remain **on hold** ... ?

Comment: If you think the question is still **incomprehensible** (even if it is edited to be comprehensible). Could **you** please edit it to be **comprehensible** ?

Comment: Can numbers be connected to more than two other numbers?

Comment: I think that editing this to be clear will basically make it into a duplicate of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69926/equivalence-classes-on-the-transitive-closure-of-a-reflexive-relation); the only difference is that it has a different input/output format, which doesn't really change the fundamental nature of the challenge. As such, if this doesn't get closed as unclear, it'll probably get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @steenbergh Sure. They can.

Comment: @ais523 I guess i have to ask another challenge that is not being asked :)